# local:MvxLang failed to bind the resource text to TextView when it is part of itemtemplate of MvxListView in Xamarin app

Tags: localization, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Issue:- local:MvxLang failed to bind the resource text to TextView when it is part of itemtemplate of MvxListView in Xamarin app using localization feature in MVVMCross.

My application is Xamarin.android, using MVVMCross, used Localization feature of MVVMCross with resx file.
Running sample can be found here:https://github.com/pallaviak1/RestaurantBilling.Droid

I am getting localized string through code using below syntax in viewmodel (AllBillsViewModel) BillClickedCommand:-

```
_dialogService.ShowAlertAsync( string.Format(TextSource.GetText("InformationReceivedMessage"),  bill.CustomerEmail, bill.AmountPaid), TextSource.GetText("InformationReceivedHeader"), TextSource.GetText("InformationReceivedButtonText"));
```

Also my main view page where local:mvxLang is button attribute, which shows button text from resource of selected culture, also works well.

```
<Button ... local:MvxLang="Text ViewBillsResourceText" local:MvxBind="Click NavigateAllBills" />
```

**Problem:-** However when I am using MvxLang in controls which are part of item template of MvxListView control the localized string is blank (not populated).

**file:-** RestaurantBilling.Droid\RestaurantBilling.Droid\Resources\layout\ListItem_Bill.axml

The control which is part of item template view looks like below:-

```
<TextView android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
android:layout_width="90dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
local:MvxLang="Text CustomerEmailTextView" />
```

The mail list control looks like below:-

```
<Mvx.MvxListView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"      
local:MvxBind="ItemsSource AllBills; ItemClick BillClickedCommand"
local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitem_bill" />
```

CustomerEmailTextView resource key is present in resx files as Name: AllBillsViewModel.CustomerEmailTextView, value : "US Customer Email".

Just to add, my Localization code is as below:- 
Resource files are present in library MVVMCross.Localization, whose reference is added in RestaurantBilling.core library as well as android project.

code in core, App.cs file as below:-

```
Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxTextProvider>
              (new ResxTextProvider(Strings.ResourceManager, currentCulture));
```

BaseViewModel has below code:-

```
public IMvxLanguageBinder TextSource =>
            new MvxLanguageBinder("", GetType().Name);
```

Getting warning in visual studio output window as below:

```
[0:] MvxBind:Warning:  9.78 Unable to bind: source property source not found Property:TextSource on Bill
02-10 07:41:52.020 I/MvxBind ( 4357):   9.78 Unable to bind: source property source not found Property:TextSource on Bill
```

I could not find enough help on MVVMCross formal website, also could not find much discussion points on same. The same thing is working in sample downloaded "My Trains" when referred from pluralsight training.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my problem is resolved. ref link: [How to bind ItemClick in MvxListView in MvxListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377851/how-to-bind-itemclick-in-mvxlistview-in-mvxlistview)

This link issue is somewhat similar. I resolved the issue in below way,

whatever TextSource property I have added in viewModel, I need to put in Bill.cs class which is model

```
public IMvxLanguageBinder TextSource
    {
        get {
            //Mvx.Trace("****************TextSource get in bill.cs**************************");
            return new MvxLanguageBinder("", GetType().Name);
        }
    }
```

Then, the resource text key looks like below:-

```
Bill.CustomerEmailTextView
```

This is kind of workaround, actually BaseViewModel has TextSource property however it is not useful in case of item template case.

Please let me know if you have better solution because we are kind of mixing viewmodel and model properties.

Comment: If you want to use Resource KEys without prefixes like Bill.xxxx, just create the IMvxTextBinder without the type parameter:

`public IMvxLanguageBinder TextSource =>  new MvxLanguageBinder();`

Then, you can forget about the hidden naming convention and place TextSource in your BaseViewModel